# histogram the result of a histogram

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have generated a histogram by the following command:

```
db.mydb.aggregate([{ $bucketAuto: { groupBy: "$userId", buckets: 1e9 } }])
```

Assuming I have fewer than 1 billion unique users (and sufficient memory), this gives me the count of documents for each user.

```
User   Docs
=====  ====
userA  3
userB  1
userC  5
userD  1
```

I want to take the result of this histogram and pivot to count the number of users for each document count.

The result would look like:

```
Docs  Users
====  =====
1     2
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
```

Is there a simple, functional, way of doing this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can start with is simple [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$docs",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            docs: "$_id",
            users: "$count"            
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { docs: 1 }
    }
])
```

This will give you below result:

```
{ "docs" : 1, "users" : 2 }
{ "docs" : 3, "users" : 1 }
{ "docs" : 5, "users" : 1 }
```

Then docs without users are the missing part. You can add them either from your application or from MongoDB (shown below):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$docs",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            histogram: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            values: {
                $map: { 
                    input: { $range: [ { $min: "$histogram._id" }, { $add: [ { $max: "$histogram._id" }, 1 ] } ] },
                    in: {
                        docs: "$$this",
                        users: {
                            $let: {
                                vars: {
                                    current: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$histogram", as: "h", cond: { $eq: [ "$$h._id", "$$this" ] } } }, 0 ] }
                                },
                                in: {
                                    $ifNull: [ "$$current.count", 0 ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$values"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$values"
        }
    }
])
```

The idea here is that we can `$group` by `null` which produces single document containing all docs from previous stage. Knowing `$min` and `$max` values we can generate a [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) of numbers and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) that range into either existing counts or default value which is 0. Then we can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRange](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get single histogram point per document. Output:

```
{ "docs" : 1, "users" : 2 }
{ "docs" : 2, "users" : 0 }
{ "docs" : 3, "users" : 1 }
{ "docs" : 4, "users" : 0 }
{ "docs" : 5, "users" : 1 }
```

Comment: It looks like `$group` is a nice improvement over `$bucketAuto` for my use case.  I wasn't able to get either of your solutions to do exactly what I'm looking for but this definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out the second grouping stage in the first code snippet?  The following worked for me (excluding the zeros): `{ $group: { _id: "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $group: { _id: "$count", count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $project: { _id: 0, docs: "$_id", users: "$count" } }, { $sort: { docs: +1 } }`

Comment: @nobar here's the Mongo Playground for second code snippet. I believe it returns exactly what you need: https://mongoplayground.net/p/b5q7VZpNh0W

Comment: I get it now, sort of.  You assume that your input is already the output of my initial histogram.  I'm just starting out with this, so it isn't clear to me how I would apply your operations this way.  What is the syntax to capture my histogram as a temporary collection so that it works as input to your operations?

Comment: @nobar yes, that was my assumption, I thought you can append my pipeline stages to the ones you already have. If you want to have temporary collection, you can use $out operator

Answer (score 0):

[mickl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982054/86967) definitely got me moving in the right direction.  In particular, using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is a nice improvement over `$bucketAuto` for this use-case.  The trick to layering the histogram was just to use a `$group` stage more than once within the same `aggregate`.  I guess it's obvious in hindsight.

The complete solution is here:

```
const h2 = db.mydb.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$count", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $project: { docs: "$_id", users: "$count" } },
    { $sort: { docs: +1 } }
])
```